# PHP Mongodb query variable it doesn't go inside foreach

Tags: php, mongodb, executequery

The $rows variable contains the data I want, but it does not enter the foreach loop. I checked the $rows variable using var_dump() and it contains data. There is no error/warning log either.

```
    <?php
                        $filter = ['email' => 'example@gmail.com', 'password' => '123123'];
                        $options = [];
                        $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
                        $rows = $conn->executeQuery('my_db.my_collection', $query);
        
                        foreach ($rows as $row_info) {
                            if ($row_info != null) { //if there is such data
                                $row_info = json_decode(json_encode($row_info), true);
                            }
                        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried just `var_dump($row_info);` in the `foreach` loop?

Comment: What is the return type of `executeQuery`?